# Why I need PDOStatement::nextRowSet with stored procedure to get result?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, pdo

I don't understand PDO's behavior about stored procedure and I need some explanations (and maybe a solution to my problem).

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 with PHP 5.4 and Apache 2.2.
I'm calling a stored procedure with 2 parameters using PDO (with SQLSRV drivers):

```
$pdoStmt = $pdo->prepare('MY_STORED_PROCEDURE ?, ?');
$pdoStmt->bindValue(1, 'MyValue1', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStmt->bindValue(2, 'MyValue2', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStmt->execute();
```

Okay, here, everything works perfectly. The result of the stored procedure called is an array so I should use **fetchArray()**. So I do that:

```
$result = $pdoStmt->fetchArray();
```

BUT the result is empty. And I don't know why, I have to call several time **nextRowSet()** to get the result. So I do that:

```
do {
    $result = $pdoStmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} while ($pdoStmt->nextRowSet());
```

Then I have my result ! Yay....

The stored procedure works when I execute it directly in the SQL Server (I have a correct result with the same parameters).

So why I have to do that and is there any solution about that ? I don't want to call **nextRowSet()** for nothing...

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researches, here my own `fetchArray()` method :

```
function fetchArray($single = false)
{
    $this->row = array();
    do {
        $tmp = $this->cur->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $cnt = $this->cur->columnCount();
        if($cnt) {
            $this->nb_fields = $cnt;
            for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++){
                $this->fields[] = $this->cur->getColumnMeta($i)['name'];
            }
        }
        $this->row = array_merge($this->row, $tmp);
    } while ($this->cur->nextRowSet());
    if (count($this->row) == 1 && $single == true) {
        $this->row = $this->row[0];
    }
    if (empty($this->row)) {
        $this->row = false;
    }
    return $this->row;
}
```

Hope that will help :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `fetchArray()` method in PDO, if you want to get an array, you can do something like:

```
$result = $pdoStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

To get an associative array.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried this but still, I have the same behavior.

Comment: @VincentNicopolsky How many sql statements does your procedure contain? You only need `nextRowSet()` if there are more than one.

Comment: There is a condition to check if parameters are empty. If it's empty I do a `SELECT 'FALSE' AS RESULT` else I do a `SELECT R1, R2 FROM MyTable WHEN R1 = @MyValue1 AND R2 = @MyValue2`.
Only this :-/